# Is there a way to change the number of columns available in the standard record list view in lightning community?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, napili, community-builder, lightning-community

Is there a way to change the number of columns available in the standard record list view in lightning community? I notice that there's a limit of 4 fields. The full layout for the record list component can display more fields, but I don't want any editing allowed for any field.

**This standard record list component in the community builder.**

[image]

**This is the layout use for the record list.**

[image]

Comment: a screenshot of your requirement could help community members to understand better

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Currently in development: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEFbQAM

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit the Out of the Box Record List component. You can only change the component based on the available properties which are displayed from the builder:
[image]

As per the records being editable, you can chose the standard layout which will remove the buttons and using CSS throught the branding editor:

[image]

Using the appropriate scope. 
You can hide a column using CSS as well as disable the pointer event:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

But please note that this is not a best practice.

Further details on the Records List functionality can be found in the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_networks_napili_records_functionality.htm).